# Finding the derivative of $y^x = e^y$

Tags: calculus

I have a problem that I've been working on and I don't understand how to start:

> If $y = y(x)$ satisfies $y^x = e^y$, then when $(x, y) = (2\sqrt{e}, \sqrt{e})$, the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx} = \ ...$

I can't understand what $y = y(x)$ satisfies $y^x = e^y$ means. Any help or hints are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y^x+%3D+e^y) is a graph of the set of pairs $(x,y)$ with this property. As you can see, this is not quite the graph of a function, but there are several functions that "overlap" with the graph. The question is asking for the derivative of any of these functions. You won't find a nice "formula" for $y$ in terms of $x$, and any expression for the derivative will most likely involve both $x$ and $y$. (If you do not understand what I mean by overlap, or being the graph of a function, think of $x^2+y^2=1$ and $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$.)

Answer (score 7):

Let us use implicit differentiation

$$ y^x = e^y \implies x \ln y = y \implies \ln y + x  \frac{y'}{y} = y'$$

$$ \implies \ln y = y'(1 - \frac{x}{y}) \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\ln y }{1 - \frac{x}{y}}$$

$$ \therefore \; \text{at}\ \ (2 \sqrt{e}, \sqrt{e} ) ,\ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1 - 2} = - \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you for the clear and concise answer, cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Rewrite it as $y^{1/y}=e^{1/x}$, look up [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and ask [Wolfram](http://tinyurl.com/kmdqwmd)...